# Show data in container view on selecting a cell in Table View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to display selected country in the container view (highlighted in the first screen),

Below is my story board

[image]

This is what I am doing after the user selects the country in CountryListTableVC, but this doesn't seem to work. Please advice How I can resolve this ?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! CountryTableViewCell

    let countryName         =   currentCell.countryName!.text
    let countryId           =   currentCell.countryId!.text
    let countryDialingCode  =   countryDialingCodes[countryId!]

    var selectedCountryInfo                          = [String: String]();
    selectedCountryInfo["countryName"]               =   countryName
    selectedCountryInfo["countryId"]                 =   countryId
    selectedCountryInfo["countryDialingCode"]        =   countryDialingCode

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCountries", sender: selectedCountryInfo)
}
```

Here is the segue code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showCountries" {
            let data = sender as! [String: String]
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UserSelectedCountryTVC
            destinationVC.countryName           =   data["countryName"]!
            destinationVC.countryId             =   data["countryId"]!
            destinationVC.countryDialingCode    =   data["countryDialingCode"]!
    }

    if segue.identifier == "showSelectedCountry"{
            let data = sender as! [String: String]
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UserSelectedCountryTVC
            destinationVC.countryName           =   data["countryName"]!
            destinationVC.countryId             =   data["countryId"]!
            destinationVC.countryDialingCode    =   data["countryDialingCode"]!

        }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell what exactly happens when you try to tap on the cell?

Comment: Can you share you `cellForIndexPath`?  Why are you trying to trigger a segue?  Is the lower portion supposed to change content when you select a country as well?

Comment: @sergey, when I tap the cell, I am obtaining the values from the selected cell and calling performSegue by passing obtained values.

Comment: @dmorrow, I am triggering a segue with the hope that I cam show the selected cell values  in the container view.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think you want to segue to another view controller.  Don't you just want to `containerView.label.text = countryName`, assuming `containerView` points to the container view and it has a `label` property that is a UILabel?

Comment: But how can I get user selected countryName into container view?

Comment: I would just use `NotificationCenter` to pass data between your views as I believe a container views `segue` is called only once when the view loads. So just notify your container view when a cell is tapped

Comment: Your design is a bit confusing... `Enter Mobile Number` screen has a `ContainerView`... which holds... a TableView? or just the `User Selected CountryTVC` (which is a cell)? Tapping on that should show a Country List Table, from which the user can select a Country and then return to  `Enter Mobile Number` screen with the selected Country showing? Or?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do:

1. Right click drag from the container view to a new navigation controller and select embed
2. Set the root view controller of the navigation controller to `userSelectedCountryTVC`

Let me know if it works or if you need help.

Comment: Can you let me know if my solution worked for you? If it did, let other users know as well by accepting this as the answer.